# Increment in degree of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Can giving a power to a differential equation increases its degree?
Like for a equation like $\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}+\dfrac {dy}{dx}=0$ if we square both sides then we get a degree of 2 for the D.E. but as we can see that the degree is 1. So this means that degree of any D.E. must be anything i.e. basically undefined.
You may also look for the case of $ \dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}=0$. Where we can apply any power to both sides to change the degree which can make the degree any positive number.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken in what you think the word "degree" refers to when it comes to an ODE. The degree of a differential equation refers not to the highest *power* of the derivative of the unknown function, but to the highest *order* of derivative of the unknown function. In the equation you presented above, $y''(x)+y'(x)=0,$ the highest order of derivative is the second derivative, so the degree, or order, of the differential equation, is $2.$ Squaring it changes the powers of the derivatives, but not the orders.